# Php shell_exec returns inconsistent result when running grep

Tags: php, apache, grep

I hope someone can enlighten me and explain the following behaviour.

When using shell_exec within php the following code gives different result when running directly by php in the shell and through Apache on a webpage. It's not that I expect the values (cpu, process count, ram ect.) to be exactly the same as this is quite impossible. The problem is that some of the lines (the summery in the top) are completely missing.

The example is simple so it should be possible to reproduce on a apache/phe server,

The php code is the following:

```
<?php
  $command = 'top -b -n1';
  $commandoutput = shell_exec($command);
  echo strlen($commandoutput);

  echo ":";

  $command = 'top -b -n1 | grep -e "^\s*[a-Z]"';
  $commandoutput = shell_exec($command);
  echo strlen($commandoutput);
?>
```

When running directly in the shell as www-data (php test.php) i get the following result:

```
8147:450
```

But when I run the exact same code through a webpage (http://MY.SERVER/test.php) I get the result:

```
8147:0
```

If I print the variable $commandoutput it's easy to see what's missing. Somehow the top part of top is left out. The following line are for some reason not included on the webpage after piped through grep.

```
top - 23:17:13 up 29 days,  9:20,  3 users,  load average: 0.67, 0.85, 0.72
Tasks:  93 total,   1 running,  92 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  5.9%us,  4.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.5%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    507452k total,   453176k used,    54276k free,    41024k buffers
Swap:   407544k total,    40524k used,   367020k free,   287916k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
```

I don't think it's an permission issue, as the result is correct when not using grep.
What magic does grep do that interfere with shell_exec. I simple can not understand how the shell_exec can return different result based on how I run the script.

Can anyone explain what's going on, or at least guide me in the right direction?

**Additional Info:**
An additional example:

In the above example running the code through apache made grep not match correctly, resulting in less lines than expected.

If I turn the regular expression upside down and match on the lines I don't want instead

> top -b -n1 | grep -v -e "^\s*[0-9]"

This time, when running through a webpage, I get too many lines. The only link I can see between the to cases is the following. Grep matching fails in both tests, but as I've inverted the match in the second case it now returns every single line instead of not returning anything.

Still I have no idea why this is so.

Comment: top - different users, different rights, differents processes listed ... . . . .   .... and yes, you are using different shells as well. the results are not inconsistent - they are immanently consistent within your system configuration.

Comment: It's not that I want the values (cpu, process count ect.) to be exactly the same - the lines are completely missing.

Comment: Without the grep command everything works. I'm unable to see how different rights, different users or different processes have any impact on me pipeing the result through grep. Different shells might me an issue, I just don't understand why.

Comment: Added an additional test example where I've used grep for invert-match.